# Class="ng-hide" get appended automatically though I am using ng-show with correct syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I need to show/hide tr tag of a table as per the scope value in the controller. I have written the code as shown below but class="ng-hide" gets appended everytime with tr tag automatically though I have declared my ng-show with correct syntax.

```
<div ng-show="IsParentExist">
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr ng-show="noValueExist">
              <span>There are no records to show here..</span>
           </tr>
           <tr ng-repeat....>
              <td> </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Here is a problem when it gets rendered in DOM as below

```
<div ng-show="IsParentExist">
 <span>There are no records to show here..</span>
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr class="ng-hide" ng-show="noValueExist">
           </tr>
           <tr ng-repeat....>
              <td> </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

I have assigned the scope variable in controller as below

```
$scope.noValueExist = true;
```

Comment: Please show your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `ng-show="noValueExist"` by `ng-hide="!noValueExist"`

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-hide="!noValueExist">
        <td>There are no records to show here.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In your controller, initialize your value.

```
$scope.noValueExist = false;
```

And when you need to show your `<tr>` element set this value to true.

```
$scope.noValueExist = true;
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Until you set the value of noValueExist as true in controller, angular sets the class as ng-hide by default.Add this line in controller.

```
$scope.noValueExist = true;
```

Comment: Yes i am doing this in my controller already. Why the span get misplaced rendering above the table?

Comment: You should post the controller code as well. There seems to be a fault in your controller; it works fine on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

As user @cst1992 mentioned the issue was with span was not wrapped in .

Answer (score -1):

The span is getting misplaced because it is not supported inside 'tr' tag.
You need to use 'td' tag to show content inside table.

After replacing 'span' with 'td' tag,it gets rendered in DOM as below.

```
<div ng-show="IsParentExist" class="ng-hide">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>a</th>
                <th>b</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-show="noValueExist" class="ng-hide">
                    <td>There are no records to show here.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually, with `span`, it shows outside the table. With `td`, it shows where it should. But no `ng-hide`.